# Primes and a polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This should be easy but at this moment I have no useful idea on how to solve it and the problem is:

Show that there exist an infinite number of prime numbers that are not expressible as $p=n^2+2$.

Comment: The intended method depends on *where* in the book the question is.

Comment: I didn`t find the question in a book.

Comment: reciprocity is not necessary. The possible values of $n^2 \pmod 4$ are $0,1.$ So, the possible values of  $n^2 +2 \pmod 4$ are $2,3,$ never 1.

Comment: I don't see how this follows from Bertrand's Postulate: every interval $[x,2x]$ contains an integer of the form $n^2+2$ (when $x\ge5.5$).

Comment: You can also use Chebyshev's lower bound for the number of primes up to $x$, which is of the form $cx/\log x$ for some positive constant $c$; when $x$ is large, this exceeds the number of integers of the form $n^2+2$ up to $x$, which is $\lfloor\sqrt{x-2}\rfloor < \sqrt x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n^2+2\equiv 2,3 \text{ mod } 4$. There are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: If I were the OP, I might ask, "how do you know this"?

Comment: The most elementary proof I know of this: if there were finitely many such primes $p_1,\dots,p_m$, let $N=(2p_1\cdots p_m)^2+1$. Then every prime dividing $N$ must be of the form $4k+1$ (nontrivial, but elementary number theory), but none of $p_1,\dots,p_m$ can divide $N$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

For fun we give a detailed proof that does not use any material on quadratic congruences.  The proof is elementary, a mild variant of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.

We want to prove that there are infinitely many primes which are **not** of the form $n^2+2$.

If $n^2+2$ is to be an odd prime, $n$ must be odd. And if $n$ is odd, then $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$.  It follows that $n^2+2\equiv 3\pmod{8}$.

So it suffices to prove that there are infinitely many primes which are **not** congruent to $3$ modulo $8$.

Let $b$ be *any* positive integer. We show that there is a prime $p\gt b$ such that $p$ is not of the form $8k+3$.  Let
$$N=8b!  -1.$$
Note that any prime divisor $p$ of $N$ is greater than $b$. For if $p\le b$, then $p$ divides $8b!$. And if $p$ divides $8b!$ and $8b!-1$, then $p$ divides $1$, which is impossible.

We claim that $N$ has **at least one** prime divisor $p$  which is **not** of the form $8k_3$. It will follow that there must be primes $\gt b$ not of the shape $n^2+2$ beyond $b$.

It is easy to show that the product of two numbers that are congruent to $3$ modulo $8$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$. Thus the product of an even number of numbers all $\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$, and the product  of an odd number of numbers $\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $8$.

But $N\equiv 7\pmod{8}$, so $N$ must have at least one prime divisor which is **not** of the form $8k+3$. This completes the proof that there are infinitely many primes which are not of the form $8k+3$.

**Remark:** Note that we have not shown that $N$ has no prime divisors of the form $8k+3$. That is probably in general false. But we have shown that for sure $N$ has a prime divisor which is **not** of that form, and that is enough to settle our problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use quadratic reciprocity. -2 isn't a square modulo every prime.